# Storing and Managing offline data in Web apps

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a web app that allows user to upload some data to the web server. But I want this app to work offline as well , so if network is not availabe it should store the data in local storage and it should push the data to the server when network is available.
Is there a JS library that could simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is the [Background Sync API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync).

You could use [`workbox-background-sync`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) to make usage easier, including a built-in polyfill for the behavior on browsers that don't support the Background Sync API.

Answer (score 0):

JsStore is a client-side javascript library for performing database operations inside the browser using indexeddb. You can check that.